# Why is the callback function not working in the HOC component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions, react-hoc

I'm passing the state (setActive) to the ButtonsOur component. Further, through the callback, I pass setActive to the HOC, but I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: setActive is not a function". Why it doesn't work, and how i can fix this? In ButtonsOur component I am passing setActive from parent component via props

This is my ButtonsOur component

```
import HOC from '../../../hoc/HocPopUp';

 function ButtonsOur({ setActive, open }) {
  return (
   <div className="base__routes__button">
  <Buttons className="base__button__moreInf open-popup-exc" Click={open(setActive)}>Докладніше</Buttons>
  <Buttons className="base__button__moreInf open-popu p-exc" Click={open(setActive)}>Забронювати</Buttons>
</div>
 );
}

export default HOC(ButtonsOur);
```

And this is my HOC

```
 const HOC = (Component) => {
 function HandleChange(props) {
  function open(setActive) {
    setActive(true);
  }

 function close(setActive) {
   setActive(false);
 }
return (
  <Component
    close={() => close}
    open={() => open}
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading
    {...props}
  />
  );
  }
  return HandleChange;
   };

export default HOC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HOC isn't reading `setActive`, `open` from the passed props.

Also you need to pass the original props early on, and have the props in the HOC override them where necessary.

```
const HOC = (Component) => {
  function HandleChange(originalProps) {
    function open(setActive) {
      originalProps.setActive(true);
    }

    function close(setActive) {
      originalProps.setActive(false);
    }
    return (
      <Component
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading
        {...originalProps}
        close={close}
        open={open}
      />
    );
  }
  return HandleChange;
};
```